# Does shutdown /f allows applications to exit?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I would like to reboot a set of machines each night. If possible I want the applications to have time to cleanly exit. Will `shutdown /f` allow applications to exit and, if need be, kill them on a timeout? Or will it just start killing processes?

Comment: relevant: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true and http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/shutdown-command.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to reboot you will need `shutdown /r /f`. This will give users 1 minute to complete their work. If you want to reboot immediately you can use `shutdown /r /f /t 0`. Note the `/t 0` is the timeout **before** the shutdown begins. It is not the time the application has to shut down.

At shutdown there is a signal being send to the applications. I tested this with an editor open. I got a save message. It stayed there for 2 seconds after which the process was killed off (hard !!).

If your application does not need user interaction, it has 2 seconds. If it does need user interaction, and the user does nothing, the process is terminated.

If you want to change some of the time-outs you can try changing the registry keys found on [this page](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26476-desktop-shutdown-tweaks-combined.html) and [this page](http://www.mydigitallife.info/fast-shutdown-faster-windows-2000-windows-xp-windows-2003-and-windows-vista/). I tried the [WaitToKillAppTimeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978624.aspx) and [HungAppTimeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978614.aspx) but it keeps terminating after 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Well, shutdown /f would do a forced shutdown not a reboot. I think that you would want shutdown /r /f which would force a reboot. It would send a kill command to the apps. What they do with the command would depend on the app.

Comment: What if the app doesn't exit right away? Is the a defined length of time it gets to exit? If the apps get a choice of what to do, how is it any different from a shutdown without `/f`?

Comment: The app doesn't get a choice. /f `Forces running applications to close without forewarning users.`. So it's just a kill command. The application doesn't have the possibility to do anything. If you have applications which need time to shutdown you should call a script to send a `close request` to all apps before doing a `shutdown /f`.

Comment: Also, Shutdown /f may not do anything... If memory serves at least. A shutdown would be `shutdown /s` , reboot is /r and log off is /l.

Comment: Just tested it and `shutdown /f` does a logoff. I had an editor open and it gave me a save option. But before i could click it the editor closed (without saving). So, there is a signal being send to the application with a time-out of about 2 seconds. I think this is editable in the registry. (It is the same process as logoff)

Comment: @Rik, do you have any evidence to back up your claims?  AFAIK when Windows starts a shutdown it posts the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message to all applications which gives them an opportunity to shutdown cleanly or even stop the shutdown sequence. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @heavyd Yep. I was wrong. I was thrown by the help of shutdown.exe `without forewarning users.` It should have read `with a signal to the applications and time-out before killing.`